# Spark deep learning Import error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, deep-learning

I am trying to replicate a deep learning project from https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/making-image-classification-simple-with-spark-deep-learning-f654a8b876b8 . I am working on spark version 1.6.3. I have installed keras and tensorflow. But everytime i try to import from sparkdl it throws an error. I am working on Pyspark. When I run this:-

```
from sparkdl import readImages
```

I get this error:-

```
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-802a2258-3089-4ad7-b8cb- 
6815cbbb019a\userFiles-c9514201-07fa-45f9-9fd8- 
c8a3a0b4bf70\databricks_spark-deep-learning-0.1.0-spark2.1- 
s_2.11.jar\sparkdl\transformers\keras_image.py", line 20, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeConverters'
```

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not a full fix, as i have yet to be able to import things from sparkdl in jupyter notebooks aswell, but!

readImages is a function in `pyspark.ml.image` package

so to import it you need to:

```
from pyspark.ml.image import ImageSchema
```

to use it:

```
imagesDF = ImageSchema.readImages("/path/to/imageFolder")
```

This will give you a dataframe of the images, with column "image"

You can add a label column as such:

```
labledImageDF = imagesDF.withColumn("label", lit(0))
```

but remember to import `functions` from `pyspark.sql` to use `lit` function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

Hope this at least partially helps